# I want to get results without reloading the page again. (Asynchronously)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, code-first

This is the Code in View.

```
       <div class="col-sm-4 page-sidebar">
                    <aside>
                        <div class="widget sidebar-widget white-container links-widget">
                            <br>
                            <div class="title-lines">
                                <h4 class="m0" style="color:deepskyblue">Course List</h4>
                            </div>
                            @foreach (var item in Model.ProgramCategory)
                            {
                                <ul class="ullist">
                                    <li>
                                        @Html.ActionLink(item.courseCategory, "Index", new { crsCtgry = item.courseCategory }, new { @class = "" })
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </aside>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-8 page-content">
                    <div class="white-container mb0">

                        @if (Model.CourseCategories != null)
                        {
                            <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CourseCategories.)  </h3>
                            <table class="table">


                                @foreach (var item in Model.CourseCategories)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            @item.courseSubject
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @item.courseName
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }

                            </table>
                        }

                    </div>
                </div>
```

This is the Index method in my Controller.

```
  public ActionResult Index(string crsCtgry)
    {
        var viewModel = new DisplayCourseIndexData();

        viewModel.ProgramCategory = db.ProgramCategoriess;
        if (crsCtgry != null)
        {
            viewModel.CourseCategories = db.CourseCategories.Where(n => n.courseField == crsCtgry).Select(n => n).ToList();
        }

        return View(viewModel);

    }
```

Now, what I'm doing is, when clicks on course category all courses(CourseName & subject) under that category is displaying on same page. This is code is working correctly. But results will appear by refreshing the page. I need to know how to do it without getting refreshing. when I click on link, results has to display without reloading the page (Asynchronously) and smoothly. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You need to use ajax to update the current page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @Ajax.ActionLink instead of @Html.ActionLink. This link(http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/ajax-actionlink-and-html-actionlink-in-mvc/) will help you on what to do.

Comment: When i replace as u said, i'm getting it as error :/

Comment: No... you need to follow the link what I suggested.

Comment: It will help you guid on what to do.

Comment: I follow ur URL.but i got a problem. blogger said, "Always remember to place a reference of the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js library file after jquery-{version}.js file references, If you don't include the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js or do it incorrectly, then when you click the link to the view list of countries, an async result will be opened on the new browser tab."

Now as he said my result is opens in a new window. I added unobtrusive-ajax plugin. but where should i add  jquery-{version}.js. And what is the place that .js files are going by default. I cannot find them in my Solution Explore.

Comment: I think by default it is under the scripts folder. Just added the jquery library then after that the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js.

Comment: @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")

When I used this it says Script is does not exist in the current context. Why is that. What is @Scripts means.

Comment: where did you put the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js file?

Comment: you might want to try this <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")"></script> instead of @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")

Comment: I made it @Neil Thanks. It is working now :) thank you very much again.

Comment: Your welcome :D you might what to vote up :D hehehe... thank you